# How to make hover effect work onclick for images and links on tablets and mobile phones

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I'm trying to create responsive web page(using Bootstrap,media queries) and have 2 problems

## 1-Navbar

Inner `<li class="dropdown">`,on `<p>` tag i have applied `.hvr-underline-from-center` class (from http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/ website) , which works correctly on desktop (max-width is 992px), but on mobile phones and tablets obviously this will not work,so ***how to make this hover effect work on touch/mobile devices** ?* **How can i use media queries and change onhover into onclick,that,when you click on  `<li class="dropdown">` ,you'll see "hover" effect and  opened `<ul class="dropdown-menu subm">` at the same time?**

P.S.Don't know why in jsfiddle  `<ul class="dropdown-menu subm">`doesn't work

## 2-Images

The same thing is about images.I want the same "hovered" effect work on tablets and mobile phones,BUT with a little difference---When you click on image(*only on mobile phones and tablets*),you should see `<div class="mask">` on the clicked image ,and **it should be "hovered" untill the user clicks on "more" or on another place.**

I have read all the posts about this topic ,tried to use `:active` , `:focus` ,also changing `:hover` into `.hover`,but nothing seems to help me.Sorry if  my question is a little bit confusing, but I am fairly new to responsive web development.

Here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Jasminejjjj777/5j3fajf6/